# Nested Inline Domain Class Edit

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have a domain-class called `UserForm` with a List object called `securityVerifications`

```
class UserForm {
    List securityVerifications = new ArrayList()
    static hasMany = [
        securityVerifications : SecurityVerification
    ]
}
```

How ever, the domain-class `SecurityVerification` also has a List object called `questions`

What I'm trying to do is build a single form for the user to edit these List objects.

I can get the instances of `SecurityVerification` to save with out issue, but I can't get the instances of `Question` to save.

My `UserController` at the moment is simply generated with addition logic to `log.debug` any validation or errors for `User` saving.

And my view is fairly complex, but essentially input fields have the following with `i` being index of `SecurityVerification` and `j` being `Question` index

```
name="securityVerifications[${i}].questions[${j}].<field>"
```

How can I get nested List objects to save in a single view and controller?

Comment: What does your view / controller look like?

Comment: I just created a simple test app for this and it worked flawlessly. Have you made sure that the data submitted by the form is correct? What is the output of `println params` in you save action?

Comment: I think it's an issue with validation, but no errors are surfacing.

Comment: So, what's the content of errors? How you instantiate the classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the my issue. Basically the domain-class `Question` had a foreign key relationship property.

```
class Question {
    SomeClass someClass
}
```

The method of which passing the input fields and options back to the `UserFormController` could not relate the `String` id to the class. Throwing a type error.

By solving this issue, I used a primitive datatype of `Long`

```
class Question {
    Long someClassId
}
```

When it came to the Show or post-save edit, I simply just did:

```
SomeClass.get(question.someclassID)
```